# jQuery parallel AJAX call mixes up return values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the following JavaScript code I repeatedly make AJAX calls to my FastCGI module to query some values. At some point the code terminates when the `data` variable for the `div2` case is not `0` but contains the value that should go into `div1` while the `div1` displays the value that was supposed to go into `div2`.

I am using the Chromium Browser (14.0.835.202 (Developer Build 103287 Linux) Ubuntu 10.10) but it also happens with FireFox. I also tried using the XMLHttpRequest object alone and I got the same results.

How can this be and how can this be solved?

```
function TimerEvent() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/cgi-bin/wvvar.cgi",
        type: "POST",
        data: "cmd=get&varname=s@SYSDATETIME",
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = data;
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "/cgi-bin/wvvar.cgi",
        type: "POST",
        data: "cmd=get&varname=@LOGINSTATE",
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = data;
            if (data == "0")
                setTimeout("TimerEvent()", 50);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The ajax requests will not necessarily complete in order.  You may have a race condition.

Comment: I think there must be another solution than sequencing the Ajax. I had the same problem once and solved it by using [`XhrIoPool`](https://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_net_XhrIoPool.html) from the Google Closure Library, but I used that library anyway. Maybe a look at the source code helps.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try have them sequential:

```
function TimerEvent() {
$.ajax({
    url: "/cgi-bin/wvvar.cgi",
    type: "POST",
    data: "cmd=get&varname=s@SYSDATETIME",
    success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = data;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/cgi-bin/wvvar.cgi",
            type: "POST",
            data: "cmd=get&varname=@LOGINSTATE",
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = data;
                if (data == "0")
                    setTimeout("TimerEvent()", 50);
            }
        });
    }
});

}
```

Comment: I'd say using deferred objects is cleaner: `$.ajax(...).pipe(function() { $.ajax(...)})`

Answer (score 1):

If your requirements allows, try this:

```
function TimerEvent() {

$.ajax({
    url: "/cgi-bin/wvvar.cgi",
    type: "POST",
    data: "cmd=get&varname=s@SYSDATETIME",
    success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = data;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/cgi-bin/wvvar.cgi",
            type: "POST",
            data: "cmd=get&varname=@LOGINSTATE",
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = data;
                if (data == "0")
                    setTimeout("TimerEvent()", 50);
            }
       });
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the calls synchronously by adding the `async=false` option.